# Can you specify a 'print method' or something equivalent in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to specify a custom print method (or equivalent) for a class? Borrowing a concept from the R language (and possibly others) what I would like it a way for the interpreter to know that when I type

> obj

which is assumed to mean

> print(obj)

it should use my custom method to print some details about the object, instead of telling me the type and memory address. Is there such a feature or similar in python?

Comment: Override `__str__` and `__repr__`.

Comment: Note that `obj` is not equivalent to `print(obj)`, even at the interactive prompt. If `obj` does not evaluate to `None`, Python will automatically print `repr(obj)`.

Comment: Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary, that's exactly what I'm looking for. The answer is provided in the question you refer to, but the questions themselves I think are different and probably not a duplicate, or maybe not? Either way thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: Side note: if you are using the IPython interpreter, then you can define also other `_repr_X_` methods that can return images/latex code etc. see [rich display](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/integrating.html#rich-display), and an [example notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ipython/ipython/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb).